# Connection rejected by remote interface Firebird 2.5

Tags: c#, firebird

Me hice un app en c# que lee un archivo FDB en mi PC local para exportar datos. Para eso me tuve instale el Servidor Firebird en una version descontinuada por un tema de OSD. Hasta ahi todo perfecto. me conectaba sin problemas.
Los fallos empezaron cuando lo desplegue a produccion. EL tema es que esta aplicacion debe correr en otra pc que ni tan siquiera esta en una red. me conecto a ella mediante Envio post por una API despues de que mi APP obtuviera los datos.
En la Pc de produccion esta instalado un soft de control de fichada Control Lenox Advanced. Este soft tiene su parte Cliente y servidor. EL primer inconveniente que tuve es que en mi local me conectaba al puerto 3050 y no tenia incovenientes pero este soft usa el 9500. Pense que no iba a tener inconvenientes si cambiaba mi appseting.json y le indicaba el puerto 9500 teniendo en cuenta que este soft ya venia con un Servidor Firebird, pues crei que iba a tener exito pero no.
Tengo este error
connection rejected by remote interface
Esto me ocurre cuando en un try catch trato de abrir mi conexion.
con.Open().

Algunas de las soluciones que pense fue en instalar el mismo servidor que use en mi local. Asi que instale el Firebird 2.5 que fue el mismo que utice en mi pc local, pero sin exito.
Revise Los puertos en el Firebird.conf para que matchearan y no consegui nada.
Alguien tiene alguna pista de que puede estar pasando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paso a responderme.
Bueno. despues de tanto sufrimiento, Revise de nuevo las configuraciones y puertos.
Como habia comentado antes instale el servidor Firebird 2.5 y en el me fui a
aliases.conf y configure un alias para acortar un poco la cadena de conexion.

```
mydb = C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\PruebaReloj\RP601.FDB
```

Luego pase por el firebird.conf y busque entre la configuraciones de puerto, esta opcion

```
RemoteServicePort = 3050
```

Anteriormente le habia colocado el 9500 que venia configurado para el software Lenox de fichadas.
Luego modifique mi appsetting.json.
Colocando la ruta del archivo a mi alias creado

```
Database=mydb
```

Y modifque el puerto

```
Port=3050
```

En un principio lo que estaba haciendo era mezclando los software con sus configuraciones.
Esto corrigio los inconvenientes.

```
{
 "Logging": {
 "TokenSecreto": "****************************",
 "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
 }
},

"RutaAPI": "https://******.******.*****/",
"MiConexionString": 

"User=SYSDBA;
Password=masterkey;
Database=mydb;
DataSource=localhost;
Port=3050;
Dialect=3;
Charset=NONE;Role=;"

  }
```